# Importing a CSV file to textbox but not formatting properly

Tags: c#, csv, hex

I want to add the contents of a CSV file containing Hex values to a textbox and output each byte to a listbox.

When the add file button is clicked the contents of the CSV file show up in the textbox, each byte separated by a comma, But when I hit the write button it throws an exception.

"system format exception, Additional non-parsable characters are at the end of the string."

I cant see how this is happening as when other hex values separated by commas are entered it works just fine. the format is the exact same in the textbox (e.g AA,66,FF,EE) but just doesn't seem to work with CSV files?

```
  private void AddFileSPI_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string AddFile = "";
        DialogResult result = openFile.ShowDialog(); 
        if (result == DialogResult.OK) 
        {
            string file = openFile.FileName;
            try
            {
                AddFile = File.ReadAllText(file);
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        Value.Text = AddFile;
    }


    private void Write_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    string hex = Value.Text;

                        string[] hex1 = hex.Split(',');
                        byte[] bytes1 = new byte[hex1.Length];

                        for (int j = 0; j < hex1.Length; j++)
                        {
                            bytes1[j] = Convert.ToByte(hex1[j], 16);
                            hexValues1.Add(bytes1[j]);
                            writebuff = hexValues1.ToArray();
                            hexValue = writebuff[x].ToString("X2");
                            WriteHexValues.Items.Add("0x" + hexValue);
                            x++;
                        }
                 }
```

Comment: Maybe your CSV has some data which is not an hex value? Put the file contents so we can see it.

Comment: I made it myself in excel for testing purposes, just contains 5 hex values AA,FF,66,DD,FF this is what appears in the textbox when I add the CSV file.

Comment: Paste the exact content of the file. Excel tends to add some headers to it, extra info, header names, etc.

Comment: The last four lines of your code are bogus: what is x, should go outside the loop, etc.

Comment: ye that could be the problem alright, how do I paste the exact content of the file?

Comment: it works fine for everything else except csv. x is the array index of writebuff, would not work properly if it was outside the loop

Comment: how would you remove the extra info/ headers that excel adds?

Comment: aa ff 66 dd ff    This is all that is in the excel file @Gusman

Comment: I doubt it, there are no column names, it's not sepparated by commas nor tabbed, etc etc. IF you go to a notepad, put that exact data and try your code i'm nearly shure it will work.

Comment: Maybe there is a newline? Try to change hex.Split(','); to hex.Split(",\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change hex.Split(','); to

```
  hex.Split(",\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove whitespace:

```
for (int j = 0; j < hex1.Length; j++)
{
    string fieldString = hex1[j].Trim();
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fieldString)) throw ... // or other error handling
    bytes1[j] = Convert.ToByte(hex1[j], 16);
```

Should help...